# Actions SDK: Two instances of org.schema.type.Text in same queryPattern fail

Tags: actions-on-google

I can't create a queryPattern containing two Text fields, like so:

```
       "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "text_a",
        "type": "org.schema.type.Text"
      },
      {
        "name": "text_b",
        "type": "org.schema.type.Text"
      }
    ],
    "trigger": {
      "queryPatterns": [
        "add $org.schema.type.Text:text_b with $org.schema.type.Text:text_a",
        "combine $org.schema.type.Text:text_b along with $org.schema.type.Text:text_a"
      ]
    }
```

This will always result in a failure to match the intent (for example "add something with another").

However, I *can* use two Color types:  If you change "Text" to "Color" in the above, and say "add red with blue" or "combine auburn along with green" then it matches and fires the intent.

I am creating deep-link intents only (i.e., commands, not a back-and-forth dialog), so I don't think DialogFlow will help me?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is that AoG is treating text parameters as "greedy", so a second parameter never matches because the first parameter has captured all the text. You don't see this with specific types, because it does more narrow matching for them.

You may actually try to use Dialogflow - it does work for deep linking Intents, although I don't know if it will behave the same way.

Comment: I thought it was simply a greedy match as well, but it doesn't match at all - the intent doesn't fire. If were just a greedy match and the first Text field contained the rest of the utterance, I could fix it myself with a regex.  The AoC team has asked me to document the failure, so maybe they're interested in a fix.

Comment: I yield to the team, of course, but if you had two fields that *had* to match, and only one ever does because of greediness, then I could see why it doesn't. But if you're saying that even with just one field it doesn't work... yeah... sounds like an issue.

Comment: Yes, one param works, and it will return the rest of the string.  I'm just hoping that they will fix the greedy match -- which isn't greedy with type.Color -- for Text as well.  Otherwise I guess I'll just have to do my own regexp on the single param to get the other, which isn't a big deal I guess.

Comment: Or look into Dialogflow, as I said. {: Doing regexps is a sure sign to danger.

Comment: Okay, unrelated question about DialogFlow -- can it be used like Actions SDK, with something like gactions, or is it from the web gui only?
Or maybe a better question would be... how would DialogFlow help for a deep-link command like my example?

Comment: It supports deep-linking commands, and the pattern recognition system is different. It has its own configuration, although for something like this using the web gui should be sufficient.